# Html Agility Pack empty Nodes

Tags: html-agility-pack

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<div class="contentLeft">

<h1>Hello</h1>

    <ul id="resultlist" class="stories">
        <li>
          
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

I have the following XML file, and I would like to read the "**li**" entry as follows:

```js
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(path);

var query = "//div[contains(@class,'contentLeft')]//ul";
var childNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(query).ChildNodes;
```

Now I should have an entry in the list - but I have three!
[image]

**Actually I only expect the "li" entry, does anyone of you know where the two "#text" entries come from?**

**Here are the dontnetfiddle.net link to my Problem:**

[DotNetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/q0hGNa)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve it:

1. Modify your XPATH
2. Use LINQ: `nodes.ChildNodes.Where(_ => _.NodeType != HtmlNodeType.Text);` or `nodes.ChildNodes.Where(_ => _.Name.Equals("li"))`.

I don't remember exactly but 1 of them should work.